# How to make JFace PopupDialog blocks on open

Tags: eclipse, dialog, jface, rcp

I want to get value from PopupDialog, but PopupDialog is non blocking like other Dialogs which block on open.

Is there any way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PopupDialog` extends the JFace `Window` class so you can call:

```java
setBlockOnOpen(true);
```

to ask for blocking. Do this before calling the `open()` method.

Comment: It is still not woriking after I added this  setBlockOnOpen(true);

Comment: You may also to change the shell style you specify. Maybe add `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL`